# I am coding a login page with HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html

[when I press sign up (without filling any fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7UWy.jpg)

[when I run my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apVD3.jpg)

Here is all the code if anyone is interested to help me :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Etego</title>
</head>    
<body>
<div align="center">
    <h3>Sign Up</h3>
    <br />    <br />    <br />
    <form method="post" action="">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" > <label for="username">Username</label> </td>
            <td  > <input type="text"  placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username"  /> </td>
       </tr>
         <!--  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
        <tr>
            <td align="right"  > <label for="email">Email</label> </td>
            <td  > <input type="email"  placeholder="email" id="email" name="email" /> </td>
       </tr>

            <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
        <tr>
            <td align="right" > <label for="email2">Confirm Email</label> </td>
            <td > <input type="email"  placeholder="re-enter email" id="email2" name="email2" /> </td>
       </tr>
       <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ -->
        <tr>
            <td align="right" > <label for="password">Password</label> </td>
            <td > <input type="password"  placeholder="password" id="password" name="password" /> </td>
       </tr>
        <!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
        <tr>
            <td align="right" > <label for="password2">Confirm Password</label> </td>
            <td > <input type="password"  placeholder="re-enter Password" id="password2" name="password2" /> </td>
       </tr>
       <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
        <tr>
            <td>    
                <p>
                    <td>

What is your Gender?

<select name="formGender">
  <option value="NS">non specified</option>
  <option value="M">Male</option>
  <option value="F">Female</option>
</select>
        </td>

        <td > <input type="hidden"  placeholder="" id="gender" name="gender" /> </td>
</p>
</td>  
       </tr>
                      <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <br />
               <input type="submit" name="signup" value="Sign Up">
               <input type="hidden" name="sign" value="true">
            </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    $bdd = new PDO ('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=members', 'root' , '');
    $gender = htmlspecialchars($_POST['gender']);
    $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $email2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email2']);
    $password = sha1($_POST['password']);
    $password2 = sha1($_POST['password2']);
    $reqemail = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = ?");
    $reqemail->execute(array($email));
    $emailexist = $reqemail->rowCount();
    if($emailexist == 0) {
        $passwordlenght = strlen($password);
        if($passwordlenght >= 4) {
            $usernamelenght = strlen($username);
            if($usernamelenght <= 25) {
            if($email == $email2) {
                if($password == $password2) {
                    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )) {
                        $insertmbr = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO members(username, email, password, gender) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
                        $insertmbr->execute(array($username, $email, $password, $gender));
                        echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>Your account has been created</font> </p>";
                        header('location:login.php');
                    } else {
                        echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>Your email isnt valid!</font> </p>";
                    }
                } else {    
                    echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>Your confirmation password doesnt match with your password</font> </p>";
                }
            } else {    
                echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>Your confirmation email doesnt match with your email</font> </p>";
            }    
        } else { 
            echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>Your username may not exceed 25 characters</font> </p>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>Your password must be 5 characters or more</font> </p>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>Your email is already being used by a user</font> </p>";
}
//---------------------------------------------EMPTY FIELDS ERROR-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if (!empty($_POST['sign']) && $_POST['sign']=="true") 
    if($_POST['sign']=="true") {
        if(empty($_POST['username'])) { 
            echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>please go back and fill username</font> </p>"; 
        } else { 
            $username = $_POST['username']; 
        } 
        if(empty($_POST['email'])) { 
            echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>please go back and fill email</font> </p>"; 
        } else { 
            $email = $_POST['email']; 
        } 
        if(empty($_POST['email2'])) { 
            echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>please go back and fill confirmation email</font> </p>"; 
        } else { 
            $email2 = $_POST['email2'];
        } 
        if(empty($_POST['password'])) { 
            echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>please go back and fill password</font> </p>"; 
        } else { 
            $password = $_POST['password']; 
        } 
        if(empty($_POST['password2'])) { 
            echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>please go back and fill confirmation password</font> </p>"; 
        } else { 
            $password2 = $_POST['password2']; 
        } 
    } 
?>
```

I use phpmyadmin and "members" is my browse, it has the id, username, password, email and I recently added gender thing.

Comment: use `isset()` on every operator, check if they exist in $_REQUEST, redirect the 'action' attribute to your page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: Do `$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null;` to get an email address. Don't use `htmlspecialchars()` on things coming in though, that's to escape stuff on output. Don't use `sha1` for password hashing, that's not strong enough. It's good to see you're using bound parameters for your database. If you want to see how to do databases/forms properly, see my profile for a (substantial) tutorial.

Comment: You output after the HTML has been generated. You should output in the HTML. You also should use `password_hash`, not `sha1`. Additionally your PHP is very hard to read, you should indent each control block.

Comment: If you try less white space that code your code will be easier to read and debug

Answer (score -2):

hi charles your code was very very messy but there was some function that i learn a bit maybe next time fix your code. Its for your own good too. i fix your code but your gonna use two php one is for signup.php and the second one is login.php
<--signup.php-->

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Etego</title>
</head>    
<body>
<div align="center">
<h3>Sign Up</h3>
<br /><br /><br />
<form method="POST" action="login.php">
<table>
    <tr>
    <td align="right" > <label for="username">Username</label> </td>
    <td  > <input type="text"  placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username"  /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right"  > <label for="email">Email</label> </td>
    <td><input type="email"  placeholder="email" id="email" name="email" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="right" > <label for="email2">Confirm Email</label> </td>
     <td > <input type="email"  placeholder="re-enter email" id="email2" name="email2" />      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right" > <label for="password">Password</label> </td>
    <td > <input type="password"  placeholder="password" id="password" name="password" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right" > <label for="password2">Confirm Password</label> </td>
    <td > <input type="password"  placeholder="re-enter Password" id="password2" 
  name="password2" /> </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
  <td>    
<p>
<td>
What is your Gender?
<select name="gender">
<option value="NS">non specified</option>
<option value="M">Male</option>
<option value="F">Female</option>
</select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="hidden"  placeholder="" id="gender" name="gender" /> </td>
</p>
 </td>  
 </tr>
 <tr>      
 <td></td>
 <td>
 <br />
 <input type="submit" name="signup" value="Sign Up">
 <input type="hidden" name="sign" value="true">
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

//Login.php

```
  <?php
  $bdd = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'root' , '');//make sure your 
  database name was really a members
  $gender = htmlspecialchars($_POST["gender"]);
  $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
  $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
  $email2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email2']);
  $password = sha1($_POST['password']);
  $password2 = sha1($_POST['password2']);
  $reqemail = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM members");
  $reqemail->execute(array($email));
  $emailexist = $reqemail->rowCount();
  if($emailexist == 0) 
  {
  $passwordlenght = strlen($password);
  if($passwordlenght >= 4)
  {
  $usernamelenght = strlen($username);
  if($usernamelenght <= 25)
  {
  if($email == $email2)
   {
   if($password == $password2)
   {
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ))
  {
   $insertmbr = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO members(username, email, password, gender) 
   VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
   $insertmbr->execute(array($username, $email, $password, $gender));
    echo "<p> <font color=green font face='arial' size='3pt'>Your account has been created</font> </p>";
    header('location:');
   }
   else
   {
    echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>Your email isnt valid! 
   </font> </p>";
    }
    }
   else
    {    
      echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>Your confirmation 
          password doesnt match with your password</font> </p>";

    }
   }
    else
    {    
     echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>Your confirmation email 
     doesnt match with your email</font> </p>";
     }
    }
     else
     { 
      echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>Your username may not 
      exceed 25 characters</font> </p>";
      }
     }
    else
    {
    echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>Your password must be 5 
    characters or more</font> </p>";
    }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>Your email is already 
    being used by a user</font> </p>";
    }
     if (!empty($_POST['sign']) && $_POST['sign']=="true") 
     if($_POST['sign']=="true") {
     if(empty($_POST['username']))
         { echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>please go back and 
       fill username</font> </p>"; }
     else { $username = $_POST['username'];} 
     if(empty($_POST['email']))
        { echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>please go back and 
       fill email</font> </p>"; }
      else { $email = $_POST['email']; } 
       if(empty($_POST['email2']))
        { echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>please go back and 
        fill confirmation email</font> </p>"; }
      else { $email2 = $_POST['email2']; } 
      if(empty($_POST['password']))
        { echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>please go back and 
      fill password</font> </p>"; }
      else { $password = $_POST['password']; } 
      if(empty($_POST['password2']))
        { echo "<p> <font color=red font face='arial' size='3pt'>please go back and 
       fill confirmation password</font> </p>"; }
       else { $password2 = $_POST['password2']; } 
       } 
       ?>
```

Comment: this is really nice of you! thank you so much, the only problem is that i am getting errors of Undefined index of all my fields

Comment: also, on my screen i always have a red message saying "your passwor more than 5 characters" and "email is invalid" and when i do create the acount it doesnt show in phpmyadmin and i checked, its the good browse dont worry @jeffrey acenas

Comment: @Charles check you database name not the database table. ok

Comment: they're both the same "members"